# Is the server running on host accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds

I'm aware of similar topics. After applying the solution that has worked for many I'm still
stuck with the same error.

My RDS db instance with open port 5432:

[image]

EC2 instance in which the db instance resides. Please note inbound rules applied:

[image]

The error I'm getting when SSHing into EC2 instance and trying to access database on RDS:

[image]

What debugging steps I can perform here ?

**Update:**

The source now reflects IP of the RDS instance:

[image]

Comment: The address in your error message is `18.132.64.139` but your database endpoint resolves to `172.31.41.230` (which btw shouldn't be public and open to the internet). You haven't shown any code so we can only guess why your database address was incorrect.

Comment: The only reason why I exposed the database to public is because it worked for others. I didn't have it like that to begin with. Get the same error anyway. I removed the other rules and left db to be open to the IP of the instance only. The error hasn't gone away.

Comment: Btw where did you get 172.31.41.230 ? When I typed in the endpoint it didn't resolve to that IP.

Comment: `dig usersdbprod.cey46tfgaz8v.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com +short`

Comment: @jordanm  short what ?

Comment: That's part of the command

Comment: https://dnschecker.org/#A/usersdbprod.cey46tfgaz8v.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

Comment: Ohh ... `dig` was a command. First time I'm seeing this. It did resolve to that IP. Am I using the wrong IP ? I mean I'm working with a course and I'm supposed to expose the port 5432 of the database to the EC2 instance's public IP which is `18.132.64.139` which is the instance I'm able to SSH into.

Comment: Yes, you are using the wrong IP. looks like you are using the EC2 instance IP for the database address instead of the RDS endpoint address.

Comment: I've added an update to my post to reflect changes. Still the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I added IP of EC2 instance to the RDS PostgreSQL security group inbound rule with All Traffic. It worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30166078)